# Using PHPMailer Results in many blocked emails

Tags: php, html-email, phpmailer, spam

I am using PHPmailer; though probably a version from 2012 - I haven't updated it for a while.

I am sending mail like this:

```
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail -> IsSMTP();
        $mail -> Host = "localhost";
        $mail -> Port = 587;
        $mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail -> Username = EMAIL_USER;
        $mail -> Password = EMAIL_PASS;
        $mail -> From = EMAIL_USER;
        $mail -> FromName = "My Company";
        $mail -> AddAddress($email);  
        $mail -> AddReplyTo('<Same as "FROM">', 'User Name');
        $mail -> IsHTML(true);
        $mail -> Subject = 'This is my subject';
        $mail -> Body = $body;
        $result = $mail -> Send();
```

I have had many emails bounce back using the above code.  I even removed the body variable and just hard coded "test" in there -- so I don't think my body is the cause.

I am wondering if there are other headers that I am not using that would help or does PHPMailer take care of this behind the scene?

**EDIT**:  I am really asking if I a missing any important header information?

Comment: there are many reasons a mail my bounce, what's the bounce say ?

Comment: @Dagon In Yahoo, it ended up in Spam Folder.  For another small ISP, it didn't give much info other than "This is a permanent error.... matches a profile the Internet Community may consider spam."  I know this is subjective thing, but I do feel that many will be blocking this as spam not just a couple.  Since 2/4 tests already have shown this.

Comment: ending in spam folder is not a bounce.

Comment: is the x-mailer set to PHP? If it is, that may be the cause, maybe not though. Just an idea!

Comment: @Dagon True, but the second situation is.

Comment: @pattyd  I am getting `X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1` in header; how do I remove?  Also, `X-Priority: 3`

Comment: yup there are multiple issues with multiple approaches, so i don't know what you would expect in an answer

Comment: @Dagon Not getting blocked out completely is the bigger concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I solved the issue;  the code above was not the problem and works great.

In my subject, I used a phrase regarding "verify your account information" and that got it blocked on a few ISP's.

So the lesson is, your subject matters.  I was looking at my php code and my body content before I realized this.

Comment: Very glad that you figured this out. I will remember it in the future!

Answer (score 2):

Some other things to note too when dealing with rejected mail:

- The server you are sending mail *from* matters a lot. Many, like AWS, are blacklisted by default, and you need to request special permission to be able to send mail. Use a [blacklist-check](http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check) if you're not sure.
- Always *always* create an appropriate [`SPF` txt record](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html) for your domain (in DNS). This ensures that the sending server is a verified sender for your domain.
- If you're having troubles sending mail, check the server logs to see why. Many providers (Outlook.com for example) will provide good feedback in the form of an RFC number or even a link to follow for more information.
- **When all else fails, use a mail gateway API like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com), [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com/), or [Amazon SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/).**